# Multiply column by every other column

Tags: r

Assuming I have a dataframe consisting of three columns

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=runif(10),b=runif(10),c=runif(10),d=runif(10))
```

And want to have a column of the products of all combinations except for a column multiplied by itself

```
a*b, a*c, a*d, b*c, b*d, c*d
```

The solution I'm looking for should work for any number of columns, not just five

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `combn` to create combination of names of dataframe taken 2 at a time and then write a custom function which subsets the dataframe and multiply it with each other.

```
combn(names(df1), 2, function(x) df1[x[1]] * df1[x[2]], simplify = FALSE)
```

This command returns a list of 6 dataframes (`a*b`, `a*c`, `a*d`, `b*c`, `b*d`, `c*d`)  for the given example.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `combn` directly on the dataset, specify the `m` as 2 to select pairwise combination of columns, specify the `FUN` as `Reduce` with its parameter `f` as `*` to multiply the corresponding elements of each pairwise column

```
combn(df1, 2, FUN = Reduce, f = `*`)
```